# android device xampp no return?

Tags: php, android

I have a very, very simple app. I've set it up using xampp. When I attempt to log a user into the localhost nothing happens, at all. No error, no logcat, nothing... very strange. I have tested XAMPP, it loads php pages into my browser, runs etc. XAMPP is definitely working as my localhost. I have tested the `java` class on an actual URL and it works. Here's the code:

**connect.php**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'test';
$conn_error = 'Not Connected!';

if (!mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) || !mysql_select_db($db)) {
    die ($conn_error);
} 
?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password']; 
$query_search = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password. "'"; 
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);

if($rows == 1) {
     echo "1"; 
} else {
    echo "Username/Password is invalid"; 
}
?>
```

**login.java**

```
class LogMeIn extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost/test.php");

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        try {
            username = un.getText().toString();
            password = pw.getText().toString();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            String res = inputStream(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();
            Log.v("RESPONSE", res);

            // if username and password are valid, launch main activity
            if (res.toString() == "1") {
                Intent logIn = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        Main.class);
                startActivity(logIn);
            }
```

I think it's my URL for the post. `localhost/test.php`. However I have tried the following

- localhost/test.php
- 10.0.0.2/test.php
- 192.168.x.x/test.php
- 127.0.0.1/test.php

None of them work. Probably a very simple solution and almost certainly a duplicate question but I cannot for the life of me figure this out.

**EDIT**

I changed the localhost to http://192.168.x.x/test.php and at first nothing... then finally I got a warning in logcat, like a caught exception. It says

```
05-27 23:38:42.510: W/System.err(13310): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.68.x.x refused
05-27 23:38:42.510: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
05-27 23:38:42.510: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-27 23:38:42.510: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-27 23:38:42.510: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex.Log_In$LogMeIn.doInBackground(Log_In.java:83)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at com.facilitysolutionsinc.trackflex.Log_In$LogMeIn.doInBackground(Log_In.java:1)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
05-27 23:38:42.520: W/System.err(13310): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.68.x.x (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310):    ... 14 more
05-27 23:38:42.530: W/System.err(13310): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
05-27 23:38:42.540: W/System.err(13310):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
05-27 23:38:42.540: W/System.err(13310):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
05-27 23:38:42.540: W/System.err(13310):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
05-27 23:38:42.540: W/System.err(13310):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
05-27 23:38:42.540: W/System.err(13310):    ... 19 more
```

Comment: try the same link on simulator browser and I think it should also require internet permission.

Comment: @Naveen simulator browser what is that? You need to clarify. Also I have internet permission declared in my manifest

Comment: as Willem Ellis'a answer states you need to use the system IP address now. Just for testing that the url works you can open the same url in any browser on your device. Also in your code to get the response string you can use `String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you testing it with the emulator or your actual device?

**If Device:**
Pointing it to localhost is going to make the android device think it's sitting on the local server. So will 127.0.0.1. If the device is connected to to the same network as your XAMPP server, you have to point it to the server's internal IP. If not connected, you'll have to allow outside connections to get to that machine then point to the external IP.

10.0.2.2 will only work if you are testing the app on an emulator. You can read more about it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Comment: I am testing this on an actual device. Nexus 7 tablet. The device is plugged into my PC via USB and is connected to my home network via wifi.

Comment: Okay, so if you're running your XAMPP server on a machine running windows, open the command line and type `ipconfig` and see what its internal IP address is. Use that as the URL and I don't see a reason why it shouldn't connect.

Comment: Question, so when I run ipconfig in my cmd, what is the address I'm looking for? IPV4? IPV6?

Comment: hm, I thought so too. It was actually what I originally had 192.168.x.x and it wasn't working. I'll check it again and let you know

Comment: Okay, well that should definitely be the right IP address. So if that's not fixing it, at least you know now that something else is wrong!

Comment: Looks like you have mistyped the IP address. `Connection to http://192.68.x.x refused`. It should be 192.168.x.x

Comment: well no, lol. i put the .x.x its actual numbers in the class. Ill post the full error log

Comment: No I know, but it should be **168**. Your error log indicates that you've specified the IP address to be 192. **68** .x.x

Comment: love you, that was it! I've been coding for too long today, my eyes are working against me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to tell my analysis :D

I think your problem lies in this code :

`String res = inputStream(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();`

Because you cannot directly turn an inputstream into a String by using `.toString()` method.

To convert inputStream into string, here's a little snippet :

```
public static String responseToString(HttpResponse response){
            String result = "";
            try{
                InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    str.append(line + "\n");
                }
                in.close();
                result = str.toString();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                result = "Error";
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Then modify your code below `HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);` into this :

```
 HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
 String res = responseToString(response); // add .trim().replace("\n", "") if you have newlines
```

I hope this is helpful, Good Luck!! ^^